# Time complexity for the following algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o

What is the time complexity of the following algorithm, how can I find the best and worst case in my code:

```
boolean b = true;
integer rn = 0;
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=m; j++)
    {
        rn = Math.Random() // random number between j and m 
        if(j%rn==0) b = false;
        while(b)
        {
            for(int k=1; k<=o; k++)
            {
                for(int l=1; l<=p; l++)
                {
                    //some stuff
                    rn = Math.Random() // random number between l and p
                    if(l%rn==0) b=false;
                }
            }
        }
        b = true;
    }
}
```

The first two for loops will always run so I guess this is the best case but how can I measure the worst case here?

Comment: You variable m is not defined. Should it be n?

Comment: You are using a breaking condition which depends on `Random` Function. In worst case, You may end up getting stuck in an infinite loop if `b` never becomes `false`.

Comment: @SaiBot No they are all different for all for loops. So n is not equal to m an not equal to o and not equal to p

Comment: @J.Doe how can m be different in all loops, it is never set to anything?

Comment: @SaiBot OK, let n=10, m=12, o=14, p=16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `rn` is in `[j, m]` *inclusive*, there are `m - j + 1` numbers in this range; using basic modulo logic there are `floor((m - j + 1) / j)` of them which satisfy the `if` condition. Adopting a probabilistic approach and assuming that `Random()` is uniform, the total time complexity is given by:

[image]

Where `P(m,j)` is the probability of the `if` condition being satisfied - i.e. of the while-loop not executing, and `S(o,p)` is the time complexity of the while-loop. Since the inner loops are independent of `i, j`, we can treat them separately.

While it initially looks like the inner loops will require a similar analysis, there are two key differences to note:

- `b` is never reset to *true* until after the while loop.
- The `if` condition does not cause any of the loops to break.
- But most importantly, `b` will **always** be false by the time the two for-loops break. Why? because when `l = p`, the only possible value for `rn` to take is also `p`; `p % p = 0` so `b` will always be set to false if it hadn't already.

Therefore the inner while loop only executes up to once, and `S(o,p) = O(op)` trivially. Combining the two results, we get:

[image]

Summing over the `1` trivially gives `O(mnop)`, but what about the `P(m,j)`? Using the fact that a number rounded down differs from its original value by *less than 1*:

[image]

Where in step (1) we did an index shifting transformation, and in step (2) used the asymptotic [Harmonic series summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence). Since this logarithmic term from the probabilistic analysis is overshadowed by the "bulk" term from before:

> **`O(mnop)`** is therefore both the *average* and *worst* case complexity.

Answer (score 1):

As you have random variables in your code, it would be rational to compute expected values of time complexity. Two outer loop runs in `m*n`. The condition of inner `while` is true if`j%rn == false`. As, rn is between `j` to `m`, and greater than `j`, hence the condition will be true if `rn == j`, so the chance of entering to the while loop is `1-1/(m-j+1)`. Therefore, the expected running time of the algorithm would be `m*n( sum of 1/(m-j+1) + (m-j)/(m-j+1) * (time complexity of inner of while loo) from j = 1 to m)`.

To complete the case, we should time complexity of inner while. Two loops compute in `o*p`. The iteration of running these two loops depends on the successful condition of `b = false`. As, finally `l` would be equal `p`, in running these two loops `l%rn` would be equal zero. Because `rn` is between `l` and `p`, and if `l` would be equal `p`, the probability of `l%rn == 0` would be `1`. Hence, these two loops running in `o*p`.

In sum, time complexity of the algorithm would be `m*n( sum of 1/(m-j+1) * 1+ (m-j)/(m-j+1) * (o*p) from j = 1 to m)` which is `O(m*n(log m + (m-log m)*o*p))=O(m^2*n*o*p)`

Comment: Where does the second factor of `m` come from?